# PHP zipfile won't open

Tags: php, download, zip

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this zip file fails to open, it errors saying it cannot open the file. The SELECT is a couple of BLOB files in phpmyadmin. Here is the code:

```
        $uploadQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE majorarea = 'Big Data'") or die (mysql_error());
        $files = $uploadQuery;
        $zipname = 'papers.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
          $zip->addFile($file);
        }
        $zip->close();
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);

        readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: Sidenote: `mysql_error()` won't work if you have errors. It needs to read as `mysqli_error($con)`. Use error reporting also. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: appreciate that tidbit!

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes, it's the little things that count and could lead to seeing what's wrong.

Comment: btw, I just tested and I did not see any discernible errors in the error log.

Comment: in the browser select 'save as file', then open that file with notepad, check in it for php errors